# Fazer tooltip ler tag html

Tags: html, jquery-ui

Estou usando o tooltip do jQuery e preciso exibir uma mensagem formatada com html, por exemplo

```js
$(function(){
  $("input:file").tooltip();
});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type='file' title="<b>m</b>ensagem <i>formatada</i>">
```

Gostaria que ele entendesse o html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que esse script resolveria

No tooltip do jQuery você pode usar:

```
 $(function() {
       var el = $("input:file");
       var msg = el.attr('title');
       el.tooltip({
          content : msg
       });
    });
```

No do Bootstrap você pode usar:

```
 $(function() {
      var el = $("input:file");
      el.tooltip({
          html : true
      });
 });
```

Comment: Sua resposta está correta para o tooltip do jquery, mas por uma certa coincidência eu estava usando o tooltip do bootstrap e não percebi.. agora que encontrei uma solução, seria interessante se adicionasse a sua resposta `$("input:file").tooltip({
         html : true
     });`

Comment: Melhorou rsrs..